# Jquery AppendTo dynamic

Tags: jquery, html

```
newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup3"+counter3);
```

Hi, is there a problem with my code because when I typed

```
newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup31");
newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup32");
newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup33");
```

It works but when I want to make it dynamic with the counter3 variable it is not working.

```
     var counter3 = 1;
     $("#addPoll").click(function () {
        if(counter3>5){
            alert("Only 5 Poll is allowed");
            return false;
        } 
        if(counter3==1){
            $("#removePoll").css("visibility","visible");
        }   
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv1' + counter3);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Question '+ counter3 + ' : </label>' + 
            '<input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]"><br></br>' +
            '<input type="button" value="Add Button" id="addPollButton'+counter3+'">'+
            '<input type="button" value="Remove Button" id="removePollButton">' +
            '<div id="TextBoxesGroup3'+counter3+'"></div>'+
            //'<label>Number Of Answer : </label> <input type="text" id="textbox' + counter3 + '" value="" name="textbox[]">' +
            '<br></br><br></br>');alert(counter3);

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup1");

            var counter4 = 1;
            $("#addPollButton"+counter3).click(function (){
                if(counter4>5){
                    alert("Only 5 textboxes allowed");
                    return false;
                }   
                var newTextBoxDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter4);
                newTextBoxDiv1.after().html('<label>Answer '+ counter4 + ' : </label>' +
                    '<input type="text" id="textbox' + counter4 + '" value="" name="textbox[]">');
                    alert(counter3);
                newTextBoxDiv1.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup3"+counter3);counter4++;
            });
            counter3++;
        });
```

I have added the full function of the code

Comment: what is `counter3`? what it holds?

Comment: It should works. You just have wrong value in your counter3

Comment: Hi i have updated the code do check. The counter3 is a varaible contain numbers.

Comment: Gosh, that looks more complex than it (should) need to. What is it that you're doing, or trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add a poll question with a button which contains multiple answers with the click of the buttons. I have updated the code by adding alert and variable counter3. the first alert shows 1 the second shows 2.

Comment: We still don't see what counter3 is. I only see it incremented in the end of (something); make alert(counter3) just before usage. Is this value expected?

Comment: @Tommi counter3 is a variable assigned 1

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code. When I click on add poll, it alerts 1. when i clicked on addpollbutton it alerts 2